# Working with samples, applying a function to a large subset of columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have data that consist of 1,000 samples from a distribution of a rate for several different countries stored in a pandas DataFrame:

```
                  s1      s2  ...   s1000  pop
region  country
NA      USA       0.25    0.27      0.23   300
        CAN       0.16    0.14      0.13   35
LA      MEX       ...
```

I need to multiply each sample by the population.To accomplish this, I currently have:

```
for column in data.filter(regex='sample'):
    data[column] = data[column]*data['pop']
```

While this works, iterating over columns feels like it goes against the spirit of python and `numpy`. Is there a more natural way I'm not seeing? I would normally use `apply`, but I don't know how to use `apply` and still get the unique population value for each row.

More context: The reason I need to do this multiplication is because I want to aggregate the data by region, collapsing USA and CAN into North America, for example. However, because my data are rates, I cannot simply add- I must multiply by population to turn them into counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might do something like

```
>>> df
                  s1    s2  s1000  pop
region country                        
NaN    USA      0.25  0.27   0.23  300
       CAN      0.16  0.14   0.13   35

[2 rows x 4 columns]
>>> df.iloc[:,:-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].mul(df["pop"], axis=0)
>>> df
                  s1    s2  s1000  pop
region country                        
NaN    USA      75.0  81.0  69.00  300
       CAN       5.6   4.9   4.55   35

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```

where instead of `iloc`-ing every column except the last you could use any other loc-based filter.